# Insert Statement Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert

I have 882 rows in my Table the columns are (StartDate, EndDate, Capacity, PitchType_Skey, Site_Skey) and these rows are based on 2010 dates, what I would like to do is insert another 882 rows for the year 2011, but I cannot figure how to do this, can you help. I have started my Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO Cap1 (StartDate, EndDate, Capacity, PitchType_Skey, Site_Skey)

SELECT
Add 1 YEAR to StartDate,
Add 1 YEAR to EndDate,
Capacity,
Pitch_Type_Skey,
Site_Skey
FROM Cap1
WHERE YEAR StartDate = 2010
```

Thanks in Advance

Wayne

Comment: Oh and whilst there is a `Year()` function to get the year part from a datetime, it's more performant to a range check with `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `StartDate` and `EndDate` are of data type date or date time, then you can use the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to add increment the year by 1 like this:

```
INSERT INTO Cap1 (StartDate, EndDate, Capacity, PitchType_Skey, Site_Skey)

SELECT
  DATEADD(yy, 1, StartDate),
  DATEADD(yy, 1, EndDate),
  Capacity,
  Pitch_Type_Skey,
  Site_Skey
FROM Cap1
WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = 2010;
```

---

**Note that:** As noted by @Bridge, @brykneval the [`YEAR` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/722783) is not [***sargable***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), therefore the the SQL Server optimizer can't use an index on that field inside the `YEAR` function. For better performance, use the predicate `BETWEEN`, or `<=`, `>=` instead.

Comment: `WHERE` clause needs brackets for the year function! :-)

Comment: @Bridge Sorry, I just copied from the OP question. Thanks fixed now.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud

Thanks for that so quickly but I get the following error

Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'StartDate'.

Comment: @wafw1971 - Sorry I missed that. Use `Year(startDate)` see my edit.

Comment: @wafw1971 You probably took Mahmoud's answer before the edit - try again with the fixed version.

Comment: Isn't using YEAR(StartDate) = 2010 Non-Sargable ??

Comment: @brykneval - Yes it is not. I added this as a note. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Cap1 (StartDate, EndDate, Capacity, PitchType_Skey, Site_Skey)

                 SELECT
                     DateAdd(yy,1,StartDate),
                     DateAdd(yy, 1,EndDate),
                     Capacity,
                     Pitch_Type_Skey,
                     Site_Skey
                     FROM Cap1
                      WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = 2010
```